# Using Framer-motion with NextJS (v13.x.x) and getting error: "Prop `data-projection-id` did not match. Server: "null" Client: "4" at li"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion, react-ssr

**Using framer motion in one of my Next JS project.**
**Getting an unusual console error while trying reloading the page.**

The page is using SSR from the most recent version of Next JS (V13.X.X).
Error describes as:

> Warning: Prop `data-projection-id` did not match. Server: "null" Client: "4"
> at li
> at MotionComponent

The problem is mainly with the hydration, but I am unsure how to avoid the console error.

There is some discrepancy with server and client version of the rendered code.

Below posting the HTML:

```
<div className='flex flex-col my-4'>
    <h3 className='text-xl font-bold text-red-400'>Overview</h3>
    <p className='my-2 text-base font-semibold text-red-400'>
        {fruit!.overview}
    </p>
</div>
<div className='flex flex-col my-4'>
    <h3 className='text-xl font-bold text-red-400'>Vitamins Present</h3>
    <motion.ul className={ 'flex flex-row flex-wrap my-4 ' + (fruit!.vitamins?.length> 3 ? 'justify-between' : 'justify-normal')} variants={vitCardContainer} initial='hidden' animate='visible'>
        {fruit!.vitamins?.slice(0, 6).map((c, i) => (
        <motion.li key={'fruit-vitamins-' + c.id} variants={vitCardItems} className={fruit!.vitamins?.length> 3 ? '' : 'pr-4'}
            >
            <Vitamin id={c.id} name={c.name} character={c.character} profile_path={c.profile_path} />
        </motion.li>
        ))}
    </motion.ul>
</div>
```

Providing the React snippet for Framer-motion variable and the code as much possible

```
'use client';

import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

import Vitamin from '@/components/vitamin';

const Fruit = ({ fruit }) => {
  const vitCardContainer = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        delayChildren: 0.125,
        staggerChildren: 0.05,
      },
    },
  };
  const vitCardItems = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 },
    visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1, transition: { duration: 0.25 } },
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold text-red-600'>{fruit!.name}</h1>
      <div className='flex flex-col my-4'>
        <h3 className='text-xl font-bold text-red-400'>Overview</h3>
        <p className='my-2 text-base font-semibold text-red-400'>
          {fruit!.overview}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col my-4'>
        <h3 className='text-xl font-bold text-red-400'>Vitamins Present</h3>
        <motion.ul
          className={
            'flex flex-row flex-wrap my-4 ' +
            (fruit!.vitamins?.length > 3 ? 'justify-between' : 'justify-normal')
          }
          variants={vitCardContainer}
          initial='hidden'
          animate='visible'
        >
          {fruit!.vitamins?.slice(0, 6).map((c) => (
            <motion.li
              key={'fruit-vitamins-' + c.id}
              variants={vitCardItems}
              className={fruit!.vitamins?.length > 3 ? '' : 'pr-4'}
            >
              <Vitamin
                id={c.id}
                name={c.name}
                character={c.character}
                profile_path={c.profile_path}
              />
            </motion.li>
          ))}
        </motion.ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Fruit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later it was found, that updating both "next" and "framer-motion" npm library using "npm update" fixed the issue.

If you are finding this similar issue please give "npm update" a try first and then check for other solutions.